# jquery and d3: why does my page reload when I use $("svg").remove()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I have a page that includes a dropdown menu to choose one of several bar charts to display. The page improperly reloads when the dropdown selection is changed. I have narrowed the culprit to this line:

```
$("svg").remove();
```

When I comment out that line, the HTML changes without the page reloading. But I need that line (or something similar), because I want the previous chart to go away when the new chart is selected.

I've also tried

```
d3.select("svg").remove();
```

but the same thing happens.

I've added

```
event.preventDefault();
```

but that doesn't help either.

I've made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jslutzky/t05z8qo9/) to show my relevant HTML and JS/d3.

My page is [here](https://president-charts.herokuapp.com/) if seeing the whole thing will help. Note how the page reloads when the dropdown selection is changed.

(Update Jan. 3: I have followed the suggestions in the comments/answers below, but nothing has helped. I'm still having this problem.)

Comment: Page is not reloading, the margin of `.container` changes when you add/remove svg because of svg's width. Try to change it to 1000

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, changing to 1000 didn't seem to help. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Sorry it's based on screen resolution. For me it was 1000px. I think width=100% will fix problem

Comment: You mean set div.container width=100%? That doesn't seem to fix the problem either.

Comment: nope, svg width to 100%

Comment: Hm, that doesn't worth either.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, your page is not reloading. ( If it does reload you will see a spin icon in most of the browsers title). Like @Mansov told in the comment It is the margin that changes when you `.remove()` and add the `svg`.

Comment: Thanks - how do I prevent this from happening? I tried @Manasov's suggestion to change the width, but it didn't help. I tried changing div.container's width, tried changing svg's width; neither fixed the problem.

Comment: Also, if I scroll down a little bit, and then select a different chart from the dropdown menu, the page automatically jumps back to the top before the new chart appears. Should that be happening? Additionally, I can't seem to fix the problem despite @Manasov's suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem. Whenever I refreshed my chart, I was doing a `.remove()` to the entire svg reference, and then calling my `build()` function again.

In effect, what was happening was the `<div>` containing the SVG was collapsing to 0 height, causing the page to scroll back up to fit all the remaining content, and then when I rebuilt the chart the page would remain scrolled at the top.

So what I did was make a "frame" for the chart svg to sit on top of:

```
//===================================================== Initialize build            
function initializeBuild() {
    bilSVG = this.d3.select(rawSvg)
        .append("svg");
    calculateMargins();
    bilSVG
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style("opacity", .0)
        ;
}
```

and then created a group that held the chart:

```
//===================================================== build            
function build() {
    chartGroup = bilSVG
        .append("g")
        .attr("class","bil chartgroup")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + width / 2 + ")";
        })
        .attr("x", width / 2)
        .attr("y", width / 2)
    ;
}
```

Then when I needed to rebuild the chart, I deleted the group, and not the whole SVG:

```
//===================================================== rebuild
function rebuild() {
    chartGroup = bilSVG.select(".chartgroup");
    chartGroup.remove();
    build();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @jslutzky , did you try this approach? ( _If it helped, you could accept the answer_ :-) )

Comment: @jslutzky , did you try this approach? ( _If it helped, you could accept the answer_ :-) )